# is it secured to store login session username/userid in a local storage and then pass it from page to page

Tags: php, security, local-storage

Am using the following script to authenticate my mobile app. I know how to use php hash and verify() function to hash users password.

When a user login, I stored users username/userid in a localstorage and then pass it from page to page for other database queries. Is this implementation secured.
What about attacks like

1.) Direct page access since local storage works with javascript. won't attacker be able to modified the local session username.

2.) What about session Fixation attack/Session hijacking. Would local storage protect me from that.

3.) How do Implement cross site request forgery attack on a form in welcome.html 
page.

4.) what is the best way to secure my mobile app via authentication. I have heard about token but do not have an idea with how it works with mobile app.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(){

var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
var password = $('#password').val();

        if(username==""){

            alert('please Enter Username');     
        }
else if(password==""){

            alert('please Enter Username Password');    

        }
else{
var datasend = "username="+ username + "&password=" + password;

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'login.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg){

                $('#alertbox_img').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);

                $('#alerts_img').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');


            }

        });

        }

    })

});


</script>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0); 
?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>


<?php

/*
please I know how to use php Password hash and verify function(). so forget about that
*/
require('db.php');
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);


$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where username = :username and password = :password');

        $result->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username,
':password' => $password

    ));

$count = $result->rowCount();

$row = $result->fetch();


if( $count == 1 ) {



    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>login sucessful</div>";
echo "<script>window.location='welcome.html'</script>";


}
else {

echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='alerts_img'><font color=red>Either Username or Password is Wrong</font></div>";
}


?>

<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

**welcome.html**

```
<script>
if (localStorage.getItem("username") === null) {

alert('Requesting page directly is not allowed.');
window.location='index.html'
}
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#payment').click(function(){

var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
var amount = $('#amount').val();


 if(amount==""){

            alert('please Enter amount');   

        }
else{
var datasend = "username="+ username + "&amount=" + amount;

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'payment.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg){

                alert('payment successful');


            }

        });

        }

    })

});


</script>


<input type="text" id="amount">
<button id="payment">Pay Now</button>
```

can someone help me explain and fix security holes where necessary. Thanks

Comment: Don't store it in local storage. Store it in a session instead. That way, the user id will be stored on the server instead of the client. _"What about session Fixation attack/Session hijacking."_ - Storing the ID in local storage is worse. Anyone can modify their local storage (if I change the data in it, would I then be logged in as another user?)

Comment: You should also stick to _one_ question per post.

Comment: This is a mobile app, php session does not work

Comment: is it browser based?

Comment: A mobile app? In what way? You're using jQuery? Surly you have a proper engine that renders the HTML/JS, right? They should be able to pass cookies. If not, how are you even using LocalStorage? As far as the client goes, a session is only a cookie.

Comment: i have an android wrapper

Comment: I would recommend that you look into something like [Json Web tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction/) or similar.

Comment: Ugh. My eyes are bleeding from the formatting of this code style..

Comment: @cemal you have to remove ur eye so that it will stop bleeding. You made zero contribution. thats bad

Comment: Ugly is ugly. Here is some common knowledge as a contribution. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code

Comment: @cemal  your zero contribution suggest that you knows nothing. absolutely nothing

Comment: Indeed. Just keep learning. Not only coding but also respect as well.

Comment: @cemal. lol. when you regard someone effort as bleeding and ugly what do u think. respect right. point to me what made this code bleeding and ugly. u cannot discourage and  stop commenting on my post